Upgrading Angular Material version - capturing all changes
I am trying to upgrade the angular version of my project from v11 to v12.
The previously installed angular material version was v10.
I followed this upgrade guide to perform all the upgrades, and upgrades angular material, cli, cdk to v12 along other upgrades.
My problem is now that some angular material components have changed some of their css which I relied upon such as for the mat-checkbox:
in angular material v10:
.mat-checkbox {
    transition: background 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1), box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


but in v12:
.mat-checkbox {
    display: inline-block; //added property
    transition: background 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1), box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}


Is there a way to get all the CSS and UI changes from angular material v10 to v12?
Going over the website component by component is a long task given the size of the project.
All feedback is appreciated!
I tried to search for logs or release notes but i couldn't find any. And the upgrade guide did not mention anything related to this.

its hard to get and detect all changes, but at least you can check the CHANGELOG.md of each release
something like here
